# Json_decode returning empty value - json object to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, type-conversion

I have a basic form where I am storing (in the client side) the values in a json format inside a textarea. I then plan to store these values in mysql database. I am using `json_decode` to place the json object into a regular php array. But when I check `print_r($personArray)` there is nothing. Therefore everytime I submit the form nothing gets stored in mysql database because the php array is empty. How can I store the values in the text area in mysql database? Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;
$personArray = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($personArray);


      foreach($personArray as $key => $value){

          $main_role1 = ($value['main1'] == "true") ? 1 : 0;
          $main_role2 = ($value['main2'] == "true") ? 1 : 0;
          $person_fname = $value['firstName'];
          $person_lname = $value['lastName'];
          $person_phone = $value['phone'];

          $query_init2 = "INSERT INTO person (main_role1, main_role2, first_name, last_name, person_phone) VALUES (:main_role1, :main_role2,:person_fname,:person_lname, :person_phone);";
          $query_prep2 = $db_con->prepare($query_init2);
          $insert_result2 = $query_prep2->execute(array(
            "main_role1" => $main_role1,
            "nmain_role2" => $main_role2,
            "person_fname" => $person_fname,
            "person_lname" => $person_lname,
            "person_phone" => $person_phone
          ));

        }
      }
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="data" rows='5' cols='60'>
```

JSON Object

```
    [
    {
        "firstName": "Danny",
        "lastName": "LaRusso",
        "ciscoID": "123",
        "academyID": "1",
        "email": "test1@email.com",
        "phone": "(555) 121-2121",
        "fax": "(123) 123-4567",
        "contact_role": true,
        "netacadContact": true,
        "netacadStaff": false,
        "netacadSuccess": false,
        "instructor_role": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sensei",
        "lastName": "Miyagi",
        "ciscoID": "456",
        "academyID": "1",
        "email": "test2@email.com",
        "phone": "(555) 444-2222",
        "fax": "(123) 123-4567",
        "contact_role": false,
        "netacadContact": false,
        "netacadStaff": false,
        "netacadSuccess": false,
        "instructor_role": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json_decode is working fine. The problem is when you are binding values into your SQL Statement.

```
$insert_result2 = $query_prep2->execute(array(
    ":main_role1" => $main_role1,
    ":nmain_role2" => $main_role2,
    ":person_fname" => $person_fname,
    ":person_lname" => $person_lname,
    ":person_phone" => $person_phone
));
```

You should include the ':' in the keys of the array.

Also, at the end of you query, you do not need another ;.

```
$query_init2 = "INSERT INTO person (main_role1, main_role2, first_name, last_name, person_phone) VALUES (:main_role1, :main_role2, :person_fname, :person_lname, :person_phone)";
```

Comment: `:` does not change anything. The json_object is not returning anything when I call `print_r($personArray);`

Comment: Yes, correct. But I doesn't work when I directly grab the value from the textarea `$data = $_POST['data']` and do `json_decode($data, true)`

Comment: Hmm, what is $_POST['submit']? the is no name="submit" on the html of your DEMO.

Comment: Oops for got to give the button `name='submit'`. Now there is another error but showing for this `foreach($personArray as $key => $value){`

Comment: Check the [Page](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php) for exact error when submitting. It is not the query. Look this works well if I do `$data="[{"firstName":"Jenny","lastName":"LaRusso","phone":"(555) 121-2121","alt_phone":"(555)..";`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error with the foreach. Hmm. http://ideone.com/ZLWTj0

Comment: Is this the exact php code on the website, becuase i don't see echo $data, or print_r($personArray) showing up. That would be nice.